# Is an apple developer program membership required for Push notifications for iOS

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, ios9

To add push notifications to an iOS application, do you need to have an apple developer account that is enrolled in the iOS membership program?

Comment: *sighs*... ..........

Comment: ......................... :-D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Yes , it is - see the terms here](https://developer.apple.com/notifications/)

see here -

> In most cases, Xcode is the preferred method to request and install
>   digital certificates for iOS and OS X. However, to request
>   certificates for the Apple Push Notification service, Passbook, Mobile
>   Device Management (MDM), and Safari extensions, you will need to
>   request and download them from the Certificates, Identifiers &
>   Profiles section of Member Center.